# React Native - Packager not starting

Tags: ios, react-native

I've been going through some React Native courses and storing all my apps in a 'projects' folder. Everything has been working fine, but all of a sudden I seem to be having some issues with the packager not automatically starting up when i run `react-native run-ios` while I'm in the specific project's folder. The simulator pops up, but it only shows my previous apps and doesn't contain the new one I just created with `react-native init new-app`. I've been searching around and I can't seem to find any solution to this. Any thoughts?

This is the last line showing in the terminal:

```
IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/[MY_USER]/Documents/projects/new-app/ios/build
```

Answer (score 3):

So after some digging and testing, I realize the issue is tied to the new feature in Sierra that stores your files in iCloud Drive. Not sure exactly of the specifics, but the issue was resolved when I turned this feature off.