# With react-native run-ios, Xcode stops running at IDEDerivedDataPathOverride=

Tags: xcode, react-native

I tried to test my react-native-navigation example project, but suddenly Xcode doesn't build after some messages.

I have no idea why or when this error shows up. Anyone has any idea?

```
Found Xcode project navigationtest.xcodeproj
Building using "xcodebuild -project navigationtest.xcodeproj - 
configuration Debug -scheme navigationtest -destination id=3F2836B0-4365-482E-852E-1D7812FC1390 -derivedDataPath build"
User defaults from command line:    

IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/mac/Desktop/react-native-project/navigationtest/ios/build
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer here:

[React Native - Packager not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895230/react-native-packager-not-starting)

it has to do with your iCloud Drive.

I had the same issue, but after disabling my iCloud backup, it builds really quickly.